# Getting null exception with Linq Max()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, null

I'm working with EF and a database that uses a common lookup design with two tables (T_LookupCategories and T_LookupValues) and a SequenceNumber column.
Now I'm trying to write a method that return the max sequence number for the lookup value of a specific category but a continue to get the exeption

```
The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.
Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

The code is this:

```
    public int GetNextSequenceNumber(T_LookupCategories lookupCategory)
    {
        IList<T_LookupValues> lookupValues = Context.T_LookupValues
            .Where(x => x.ID_LookupCategory == lookupCategory.ID_LookupCategory)
            .ToList();

        return lookupValues == null ? 1 : lookupValues.Max(x => x.SequenceNumber) + 1;
    }
```

Why? I don't understand.
Is correct how I check for null values?

EDIT

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace GIE.ITTeamSite.Data.DAL.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class T_LookupCategories
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public T_LookupCategories()
        {
            this.T_LookupValues = new HashSet<T_LookupValues>();
        }

        public int ID_LookupCategory { get; set; }
        public string LookupCategory { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_LookupValues> T_LookupValues { get; set; }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace GIE.ITTeamSite.Data.DAL.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class T_LookupValues
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public T_LookupValues()
        {
            this.T_Phases = new HashSet<T_Phases>();
            this.T_Phases1 = new HashSet<T_Phases>();
            this.T_Phases2 = new HashSet<T_Phases>();
            this.T_Projects = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects1 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects2 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects3 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects4 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects5 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects6 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Projects7 = new HashSet<T_Projects>();
            this.T_Tasks = new HashSet<T_Tasks>();
            this.T_Tasks1 = new HashSet<T_Tasks>();
            this.T_Tasks2 = new HashSet<T_Tasks>();
        }

        public int ID_LookupValue { get; set; }
        public int ID_LookupCategory { get; set; }
        public string LookupValue { get; set; }
        public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual T_LookupCategories T_LookupCategories { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Phases> T_Phases { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Phases> T_Phases1 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Phases> T_Phases2 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects1 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects2 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects3 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects4 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects5 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects6 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Projects> T_Projects7 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Tasks> T_Tasks { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Tasks> T_Tasks1 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<T_Tasks> T_Tasks2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: show `T_LookupCategories` and `T_LookupValues` classes

Comment: There are 2 lines in this code, so which one gives you an exception?

Comment: What's the type of SequenceNumber? Is it nullable?

Comment: Most probably `T_LookupValues` has a property of type `int` of which the corresponding column in the database is nullable and some value in such column is NULL.

Comment: Hello, I posted the two classes ad required. They are generated by EF.

Comment: In the database `SequenceNumber` is not nullable as the property in the `T_LookupValues` class. Anyway I solved with the code posted by @tschmit007, probabibly @Shaharyar's code works too but I've not tried. But I've to do a double check? Thank you everyone for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably:

```
return lookupValues == null ? 1 : (lookupValues.Max(x => (int?)x.SequenceNumber) ?? 0) + 1;
```

or as you materialize the List

```
return lookupValues == null ? 1 : 
    lookupValues.Count == 0 ? 1 :
        lookupValues.Max(x => x.SequenceNumber) + 1;
```

the point is most certainly that `x.SequenceNumber` is an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone explained in the comments that you could have a `null` value in your column but not in your entity class.

You should either edit your class to accept nullable int (`int?`) or edit this LINQ:

```
IList<T_LookupValues> lookupValues = Context.T_LookupValues
    .Where(x => (int?)x.ID_LookupCategory == (int?)lookupCategory.ID_LookupCategory)    //casting to "int?"
    .ToList();
```

Comment: not sure the cast at this point solve the problem. At this point the problem is handled by the db server that can compare an int with a dbnull.

Comment: Yeah, I am also looking to correct the last line. Which I think you have done it well. As the OP is not responding, we can only have guesses.